# Best way to support multi-login on AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm refactoring for a client an app that should support OpenID, Facebook Connect and custom authentication (email+password).
Suppose that i have:

```
class MyUser(db.Model):
    pass
class Item(db.Model):
    owner = db.ReferenceProperty(MyUser)
```

I was thinking to implement different authentication systems this way:

```
class OpenIDLogin(db.Model): # key_name is User.federated_identity()? User.user_id()?
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(MyUser)

class FacebookLogin(db.Model): # key_name is Facebook uid
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(MyUser)

class CustomLogin(db.Model): # key_name is the user email
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(MyUser)
    password = db.StringProperty()
```

Is there a better solution? There is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699751/google-app-engines-db-userproperty-with-rpxnow) but i can't understand if that's the right solution for me.
I've already developed an app using the Users API and another one using Facebook Connect in the past, so i know how to deal with the both, the problem is to wire them together. Switching to another framework isn't an option unfortunately.

Comment: Facebook now uses a draft version of OAuth 2.0, which depends on https for security.  Beware: App Engine's URL Fetcher service does not currently validate https certificates, which means your app will be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle and DNS poisoning attacks; potentially exposing your Facebook secret keys.  You'll have to decide for yourself whether you think someone might successfully mount such an attack on Google's URL Fetcher machines and whether such a secret key leak is acceptable.

Comment: This is on my roadmap in a couple of months, so I'd appreciate an answer as well.

Comment: @Forest.  Thanks for the heads up.  If I understand correctly the potential threat you're speaking of lies between GAE servers and Facebook servers.  This is not a user level "Starbucks WiFi" threat.  Is that correct?

Comment: A man in the middle, between Google and Facebook. I think it's pretty safe to assume that's secure enough for every application that you can/are-willing-to host on AppEngine.

Comment: mjhm, that is correct.  To everyone even mildly interested in making https requests from App Engine, I recommend adding your star to this bug report:  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i used something like:

```
key_name = '%s|%s' % ('facebook', facebook_uid)
```

and:

```
key_name = '%s|%s' % ('myapp', email)
```

It's good and lookup is fast, but it lacks support for multi-provider login (i.e. user wants to be able to login using both google and facebook).

This is my actual solution:

```
class User(db.Model):
    accounts = StringListProperty() # ['facebook|1234', 'google|4321']
    email = StringProperty()
    password = StringProperty()
```

Lookup is slower but it's done just once on login, after that i store user.key().id() in session and use that. It's also good because you can link the user to an email/password combo. The downside is that you must enforce uniqueness manually on your keys (email, facebook id, google id etc...).

Answer (score 2):

I would take a close look at [tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org) and its [Authentication extension](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy-ext-auth/source/browse/#hg/tipfy/ext/auth).<sup>*</sup>

They have implemented a [Universal User model](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy-ext-auth/source/browse/tipfy/ext/auth/model.py) that can be used with App Engine's default users API,    own auth or third party authentication methods (OpenId, OAuth etc).

[Here](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/auth/) is the documentation, look for **MultiAuthMixin** section.

<sup>*good programmers write good code; great programmers steal great code</sup>

Comment: Already did that, unfortunately integrating that in webapp is a pain, i'm really hoping for webapp-improved to implement that.